# Android image click in horizontal page view

Tags: android, image, click, swipe, pageviews

I've implemented horizontal page view with many images. And I'm trying to create a click event on the image.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pbase);
    ImageView binfo,bheacno;

    tvHeacno=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvheacno);
    heacno=getHeacno();
    tvHeacno.setText(heacno);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter=new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mythreepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    binfo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivinfo);
    bheacno=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivheacno);
    binfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    bheacno.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

then i've MyPagerAdapter class and the onclik method.
it returns null to binfo and hence fails at binfo.setOnClickListener(this) 
I've done image click before on normal pages successfully. Is it because of horizontal page views? How can I solve this issue??

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_gravity="top" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivinfo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/information" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="   Information  " />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivheacno" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/heacno" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Get HEAC Number" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivpi" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/pi" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Personal Information" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivassn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/assn" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Add Social Security Number" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivvssn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/vssn" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="View Social Security Number" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivdssn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dssn" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Delete Social  Security  Number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivali" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ali" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Add Low Income" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivvli" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/vli" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="View Low Income" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/ivdli" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dli" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" android:text="Delete Low Income" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can we see more code? this is not enough to figure out the problem (you're using this and we dont know the context where this is being executed)

Comment: check `binfo` for being `null`, you obviously cannot call any methods on `null` objects

Comment: Can you share the exception you receive ?

Comment: yes, it is returning null..y is it so?

Comment: the exception it receives is 'null'

Comment: its just the normal code for image click. the only difference being, the images are in horizontal view pages.

Comment: the xml page which acts as the base page for swiping pages and java page is linked in manifest. But the swiping pages contains the images. Is that why it is returning null? should i link the swiping pages too to java page? how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binfo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivinfo);
bheacno=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivheacno);
binfo.setOnClickListener(this);
bheacno.setOnClickListener(this);
```

the above code should be in the MyPagerAdapter class.
The problem is solved. thanx guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this. it may help you.

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                                  Your code 
                                            }
                                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Share the layout xml, I think the error is at binfo declaration, might have some hierarchy.

binfo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivinfo);